# Make views visible one by one; android

Tags: android, imageview

I'm having trouble with making views visible. As in: they do all appear, but at the same time, whereas I would like to show them with some delay in between. Currently I have the following code, which should make it more clear:

```
public void performExperiment (View v) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Experiment has started on view: " + v);
    final ArrayList<FocusPoint> permutation = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(focusPoints));
    Collections.shuffle(permutation);

    for (FocusPoint fp: permutation) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            fp.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
            //fp.invalidate();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG, "Sleep failed");
        }
    }
}
```

The FocusPoint-class is an extension of ImageView in Android and the method is called upon a button-click.

What needs to happen is that all the views show up in a random order on the screen, with a second between them. This code however waits for 16 seconds (the amount of views is 16) and then shows all the views at once. I tried invalidating my the view to redraw it, and I also tried to take 'fp.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE)' out of the try-catch block, but both didn't work. (Of which the latter obviously doesn't work, I didn't really expect that to work, but I'm getting really desperate :P) I have been searching for hours now, and none of the StackOverflow-pages and other fora/documentation had an answer for this problem. How can I make sure that the focuspoint draws, before the loop continues to the next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Thread.sleep(ms)` to delay the UI thread is a very dangerous idea, and as you can see, it doesn't lead anywhere. By blocking the thread for 16 seconds, you are effectively freezing the application for that period - including any redraws and other event handling that might happen during that time. Don't ever do that.

Instead, use a `Handler` and its `postDelayed(Runnable, ms)` method to schedule visibility changes in the future. Handlers work by adding messages to the event loop, so they don't disrupt normal behavior.

Check this modified version of your code:

```
private static final long FP_SHOW_DELAY_MS = 1000;
private Handler handler = new Handler();

public void performExperiment (View v) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Experiment has started on view: " + v);
    final ArrayList<FocusPoint> permutation = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(focusPoints));
    Collections.shuffle(permutation);

    for (int i = 0; i < permutation.size(); i++) {
        final FocusPoint fp = permutation.get(i);

        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                fp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }, (i + 1) * FP_SHOW_DELAY_MS);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks alot for the answer! It works very well. I did not really know the purpose of the handler in Android, until now. I had seen it before, but I didn't know I could use it here. Thanks, I think this will really help in my further Android-programming as well. (I'm still quitte curious to why my code wouldn't work btw. It didn't crash my program or anything, but just drew everythin after 16 seconds. Does it have something to do with when the views are updated?)

Comment: I'm glad I could help :) Your code didn't work because `invalidate` doesn't do the actual drawing, but queues it for later - the same way you did with the Handler. If you block the UI thread, its event loop (Looper) can't get to the message.

When the sleep is done, all 16 updates are quickly performed one after the other, this is why it seems that they all happen at once.

Comment: Also, this whole deal is not Android specific, any event loop based GUI is vulnerable. For example, should you block the UI thread in a Windows Forms application for long enough, you would get white outs and "Application is not responding" warnings quick.